# joomla registration form and multiple groups

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to create a custom registration form in joomla with the possibility to select a group. 
Example 1: 
User A selects the group "Group1" and displays the registration form with the fields "First name," 
The user selects the B group "Group2" and displays the registration form with the fields "Name, Last Name, City, away,"

Example 2 with Photos: 
[image]

There is a component in joomla that can do this? 
Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with ChronoForms (especially v5) using DIV IDs or similar for the fields you want to show or hide together with a few lines of JavaScript.

The choice can be controlled via check box(es) or a drop down menu etc.

There are some examples of this in the ChronoEngine forums e.g.:

http://www.chronoengine.com/forums/posts/f5/t95421/hide-unhide-div-container-easy.html?hilit=show+hide+dropdown+javascript

You can find more examples by searching the forums for "hide unhide javascript"

Answer (score 1):

Two form components in Joomla with extensive options and database integration are ChronoForms and RSForms Pro which I recommend.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/4964
[http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508[2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508)